# Umbraco Template Layout Transfers

Tags: umbraco

I have one umbraco site with various templates and layouts setup. I will like to transfer the template types and layouts to a new site i am building which tools or scripts can i use to do this. The export document type and import doucment types does not copy all the fields across.

Answer (score 1):

You could use USync or Courier.  Usync is free and Courier is free for use on local domains only otherwise you would have to purchase a license. Both of these options involve a learning curve, especially USync.

Your only other option is manually - personally, this is the option I would choose.  With templates, I would create the items with exactly the same names in the Umbraco back office first (this looks after the database aspect of template setup) and would set up some blank template files on the file system.  Then I would copy across the old template files to overwrite the new blank ones... done!